# Task.WhenAll slower than await in a for loop for multiple http calls with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I have a web api call executing 10 http calls. Each http call takes 80 ms to complete. I have realized that the first time that the api method is executed Task.WhenAll is faster (400ms) than the  await in the for loop (800ms). In every subsequent call `Task.WhenAll` is slower (4.2s !!). 
If I wait for sometime the `Task.WhenAll` is getting executed again fast. The  `await` in the for loop takes every time the same time.

```
async Task GetData(HttpClient client)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://someurl.com");

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
}

public async Task GetWithForLoop()
{
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient(); //IHttpClientFactory

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await GetData(client);
    }
}

public async Task GetWithTaskWhenAll()
{
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(GetData(client));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

I have added a stop watch to monitor every http call execution time.

**For loop**   
(In every subsequent call same results) 800ms total execution time

```
Elapsed time 86 ms<br>
Elapsed time 84 ms<br>
Elapsed time 84 ms<br>
Elapsed time 84 ms<br>
Elapsed time 84 ms<br>
Elapsed time 97 ms<br>
Elapsed time 84 ms<br>
Elapsed time 84 ms<br>
Elapsed time 87 ms<br>
Elapsed time 84 ms<br>
```

**Task.WhenAll (First execution)**  
400ms total execution time

```
Elapsed time 361 ms<br>
Elapsed time 333 ms<br>
Elapsed time 331 ms<br>
Elapsed time 342 ms<br>
Elapsed time 348 ms<br>
Elapsed time 338 ms<br>
Elapsed time 342 ms<br>
Elapsed time 350 ms<br>
Elapsed time 346 ms<br>
Elapsed time 342 ms<br>
```

**Task.WhenAll (Second execution)**  
4.2 s total execution time

```
Elapsed time 101 ms<br>
Elapsed time 93 ms<br>
Elapsed time 579 ms<br>
Elapsed time 1097 ms<br>
Elapsed time 1614 ms<br>
Elapsed time 2125 ms<br>
Elapsed time 2653 ms<br>
Elapsed time 3169 ms<br>
Elapsed time 3671 ms<br>
Elapsed time 4180 ms<br>
```

Comment: dispose your clients and try again (`using(var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient()) { ... }`)

Comment: What is your ClientFactory doing?  Ideally there should be a single client per run (not disposed, sorry @vasily.sib): https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: It is probably the tasks.Add().  To add you have to get all the existing tasks.  So each loop takes a little longer.

Comment: @jdweng - that's not really borne out by the results of the first run - they seem pretty consistent.

Comment: Can you show the actual code to reproduce your results, including the code to measure the result?

Comment: @vasily.sib HttpClientFactory takes care of the handlers. So no need for disposing.

Comment: @poke I will create a ready to run controller and share it.

Comment: Consider the possibility that this is an issue on the endpoint.  Maybe it's not written to handle parallel requests of such frequency.  When you perform request-response in a loop it doesn't have to perform the task at the same time as the exact same task.

Comment: @Archer I think you have point. It seems logical. Task.WhenAll will send them nearly parallel.

Comment: I suggest that you make one more experiment, by using a loop to add the tasks in a list, and then use a second loop to await each task in the list (without using `WhenAll`). My prediction is that you'll get a behavior similar to the `WhenAll` version, proving that `WhenAll` is not the actual problem here.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You are right. I have the same results like WhenAll.

Comment: @pkofos so it seems that your `HttpClient` really dislikes doing more than one requests concurrently!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I believe it is web server throttling on concurrent requests.

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where you measure performance?

Comment: @pkofos this is certainly possible. You could experiment with a different url (another server). I bet that in general you'll get much increased throughput with the parallel approach!

Comment: How are you running the API? Is it just running in Visual Studio (i.e. IIS Express)? IIS Express is single-threaded, so *nothing* can happen concurrently. To correctly profile, you need to run it on a real web server, i.e a local IIS or deployed remotely.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I had the same results on IIS. It is probably very strict strategy at the webserver for concurrent requests. Even if I sent 2 tasks with WhenAll the second takes significant more time.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of Web API's are protected against being abused for other peoples automation or spammed requests. They will put a limit on the number of concurrent connections. And they might even actively put communicaiton to that client on cooldown if it detects overuse.

Due to the huge difference in execution (more then 3000 ms), I a betting it is such a protection or connection limitation. You are spamming too many requests in to short a time and the API writer really does not like that.

@vasily.sib also noticed that you forgot to dispose your connections. It could actually be that the limitation is on your end and this time is how long the connection is given to "time out". However <4's seems like a very low timeout. If disposing fixes it, it was on your end. If disposing did not fix it, it could have been on their or your end (or even both).

Comment: Consistent results when repeating the for loop proves this is not relevant.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say, but still the fact that running a for loop repeatedly provides consistent results means that there is no type of blocking or throttling being performed on the server.

Comment: @Archer Connections limits and warning tresholds are trivially exhausted by any form of Multitasking and this at least has the attempts of doing that.

Comment: There is no need for disposing an HttpClient is .net core. Also in .net is a very bad practice.

Comment: It's perhaps better said as "there is no need to dispose `HttpClient` when using `IHttpClientFactory`". There's nothing unique to .NET Core that makes it to where you don't have to dispose of things. If you new up `HttpClient` directly, you'd be responsible for disposing of it, .NET Core or not.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes you are right. I already wrote it under the first post.

Comment: @ChrisPratt So IHttpClientFactory basically works as a Garbage Collector for non-managed resources? Nice QoL change.

Comment: @Christopher: No. It's very literally a factory. It maintains an internal store of named `HttpMessageHandler` instances and exposes `CreateClient` to create a new `HttpClient` instance with an appropriate existing `HttpMessageHandler` attached. It's dependency injected, so the IoC container manages the factory's lifetime, and it disposes of its managed resources when it's disposed. Long and short, you just pull clients out of it as necessary and you don't have to worry about their lifetimes or overrunning the connection pool.